# ROC curves for unbalanced datasets

Tags: classification, roc, unbalanced-classes

Consider an input matrix $X$ and a binary output $y$.

A common way to measure the performance of a classifier is to use ROC curves.

In a ROC plot the diagonal is the result that would be obtained from a random classifier. In case of an unbalanced output $y$ the performance of a random classifier can be improved choosing $0$ or $1$ with different probabilities.

How can the performance of such classifier be represented in a ROC curve plot?
I suppose it should be a straight line with a different angle, and not the diagonal anymore?

[image: ROC curve example]

Comment: You may want to try precision-recall curve instead, "The Precision-Recall Plot Is More Informative than the ROC Plot When Evaluating Binary Classifiers on Imbalanced Datasets", https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4349800/, a likely more accessible website created by the authors of the paper, https://classeval.wordpress.com/simulation-analysis/roc-and-precision-recall-with-imbalanced-datasets/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ROC curves are insensitive to class balance. The straight line you obtain for a random classifier now is already the result of using different probabilities of yielding positive (0 brings you to (0, 0) and 1 brings you to (1, 1) with any range inbetween).

Nothing changes in an imbalanced setting.

Comment: I find it helpful to consider the meaning of the area under curve to see why the diagonal does not change. AUC can be interpreted as the probability that a randomly selected positive example will have a higher score than a randomly selected negative example.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve). This makes it clearer to me why class imbalance is not an issue.